# Is there a sympy defaults file, like matplotlib has ~/matplotlib/.matplotlibrc?

Tags: python, matrix, default, sympy

Is there a `sympy` defaults file, like `matplotlib` has `~/matplotlib/.matplotlibrc`?

Presently, the default LaTeX output for the following code uses `smallmatrix`, which is too small:

```
>>> mat = Matrix([[0 1], [1 0]])
>>> latex(mat)
\left[\begin{smallmatrix} ...
```

I would like it to use `matrix` by default. For now, I do it with:

```
>>> latex(mat, mat_str='matrix')
\left[\begin{matrix} ...
```

I would like to have the ability to set a default without having to use `mat_str='matrix'`

Answer (score 1):

You could always just write your own small wrapper to `latex`

```
def latex(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('mat_str', 'matrix')
    sympy.latex(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you want to change the behavior of `init_printing`, there's an [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=3612) for it.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like sympy reads any defaults files. Matrices types are hardcoded in /sympy/printing/latex.py with the following comment:

> mat_str: Which matrix environment string to emit. "smallmatrix", "matrix",
>   "array", etc. Defaults to "smallmatrix" for inline mode, "matrix" for
>   matrices of no more than 10 columns, and "array" otherwise.

You can change hardecoded defaults by modifying the following fragment (currently at line 1169):

```
mat_str = self._settings['mat_str']
        if mat_str is None:
            if self._settings['mode'] == 'inline':
                mat_str = 'smallmatrix'
            else:
                if (expr.cols <= 10) is True:
                    mat_str = 'matrix'
                else:
                    mat_str = 'array'
```

Just replace 'smallmatrix' with 'matrix' and use mat_str parameter if you need to override it.